# Can't access object data from API call

Tags: reactjs

I get data from API which return an array of countries objects. However, I couldn't to extract info from the objects, like name, flag...
What's was wrong? How can I resolve the problem? I tried with map to create an array with 2 properties: name and flag, but I doesn't work, like:
const countriesInfo=ranCountries.map(country => {name:country.name, flag: country.flag}
});

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
 

function App() {

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect')
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('promise fulfilled')
        setCountries(response.data)
      })
  }, []);
    

  console.log('render', countries.length, 'notes');
  console.log(countries[244].name); ???

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Country</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Since the API call is async you have to account for the initial renders where the value is not present. Once a response is received and `setCountries` is called the component will rerender and the data will be available. You should first make a check to see if the data has loaded before trying to access the 245th item i.e.` if (countries.length > 0) console.log(countries[0].name);`

Comment: you can also check if the object exists like this ```countries[244]?.name```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      console.log("promise fulfilled", response.data);
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* since response is in array of objects we should use map function inorder to iterate each object inside array */}
      {countries.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <h1> Country Name :{item.name}</h1>
          <img src={item.flag} /> {/* // flag */}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> since response is in array of objects we should use **map** function in order to iterate each object inside array .